# css horizontal navigation bug

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am having trouble styling my css navigation bar.  The last list item is dropped to a second line which looks really bad for the website.  Can someone look over my code and find what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="HorizNav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="horiznav-first">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="horiznav-last">Social Media</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#HorizNav ul {
  float: right;
  text-Align: left;
  width: 465px;
  height: 50px;

  background: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;

}

#HorizNav ul li { float: left; }

#HorizNav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #aa00ff;
  color: #fff;

  width: 92px;
  height: 20px; /* height minus padding-top */

  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;

  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

#HorizNav ul li a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #aa00ff;
}

#HorizNav ul li a#horiznav-last { none; }
```

Comment: increase your UL width to **515px**

Comment: just `515px` as said by @sandeep don't give auto it break the menu bar while re-size or looking in portable device.

Comment: Are you trying to make the page reactive to the screen width? You should then check out @media queries. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ . Otherwise, like said elsewhere, the only way to prevent a narrow window from wrapping your elements is to put them inside an element with a specific width.

Answer (score 1):

Change this rule in your CSS

```
#HorizNav ul {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  width: 515px;
  height: 50px;

  background: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;

}
```

DEMO  http://jsfiddle.net/n5B5W/6/